# Merge two records which should not have been history handled

Tags: teradata

I have a requirement where i have to merge two records into one, where the history should not have been handled. Here in the below example, the major columns are segment_type and segment_value based on these two records, if any one of them changes the history should be handled. Here the NR records should not have been history handled. Is there any way to merge these two records into one.?

```
PARTY_ID    SEGMENT_TYPE    SEGMENT_VALUE   SEGMENT_START   SEGMENT_END
144,088        RC                  LC       7/11/2010       12/31/2011
144,088        LB                  LC       12/31/2011      5/26/2014
144,088        NR                  ?       5/26/2014        6/7/2015
144,088        NR                  ?       6/7/2015         11/22/2017
144,088        SM                  ?       11/22/2017         ?
```

Expected output:

```
PARTY_ID    SEGMENT_TYPE    SEGMENT_VALUE   SEGMENT_START   SEGMENT_END
    144,088        RC                  LC       7/11/2010       12/31/2011
    144,088        LB                  LC       12/31/2011      5/26/2014
    144,088        NR                  ?       5/26/2014        11/22/2017
    144,088        SM                  ?       11/22/2017         ?
```

This not getting handled, here the history is correct as segments have changed each time but since we have used group by it getting handled.

```
PARTY_ID    SEGMENT_TYPE    SEGMENT_VALUE   SEGMENT_START   SEGMENT_END
148,478       GI                ?             7/10/2011 5/19/2015
148,478       KA                ?             5/19/2015 7/8/2015
148,478       GI                ?             7/8/2015  8/27/2015
148,478       KA                ?            8/27/2015  10/6/2015
148,478       GI                ?            10/6/2015  11/26/2015
148,478       KA                ?          11/26/2015   2/24/2016
148,478       GH                 ?          2/24/2016   2/25/2016
148,478       KA                  ?         2/25/2016   10/16/2016
148,478       GI                ?            10/16/2016 ?
```

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, 
Added the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Added a scenario whcih is not getting handled

Comment: You should also show the expected output from this new scenario.

Comment: This scenario should not be covered under our query, basically it should handle only for consecutive rows, Like 
NR
NR
and not like 
NR
LR
NR
I hope its clear.

Comment: Please let me know if the explaination is clear to u

Comment: Is there any way to handle only the first case and exclude all the second cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata implements a quite unknown extension to Standard SQL for exactly this scenario, it's based on PERIODs, but can easily be adjusted for seperate begin/end columns:

```
SELECT PARTY_ID,SEGMENT_TYPE,SEGMENT_VALUE,
   -- this splits the period back to seperate columns 
   Begin(pd) AS SEGMENT_START, NullIf(End(pd), DATE '9999-12-31') AS SEGMENT_END
FROM
 ( 
   SELECT NORMALIZE -- this returns your normalized result as a period
      PARTY_ID,SEGMENT_TYPE,SEGMENT_VALUE,
      PERIOD(SEGMENT_START,Coalesce(SEGMENT_END, DATE '9999-12-31')) AS pd
   FROM vt
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: I have added a scenario which is not getting handled.

Comment: Is there any way to handle only the first case and not the second one?

Comment: @user3901666: `NORMALIZE` will work as expected, but I forgot to a `COALESCE` to avoid a NULL period, fixed.

Comment: @dnoeth This looks like `td_normalize_overlap_meet` functionality. Are they redundant?

Comment: @JNevill: Same functionality, but NORMALIZE is newer. Simple keyword vs. complex syntax :-)

Comment: Holy smokes that is so nice. I've written td_normalize_overlap_meet so many times I almost have the syntax memorized. I have a lot of code to update. This is very exciting. Thanks @dnoeth!

Comment: @JNevill: Btw, there's also NORMALIZED Tables, I like them when you need to have some additional columns you want to ignore. Simply Insert/Select the data into a volatile Normalized Table...

Comment: @dnoeth I will have to take a look into that. I spend a ton of time working with period data and the ability to normalize it before joining on intersect saves a lot of resources.

Comment: Hi @dnoeth,
Thanks!!. I am getting one error like invalid period value constructor.The beginning bound must be less than the ending bound.
Is there any issue with the data? How can i bypass that?

Comment: Then you got bad data, i.e. a SEGMENT_END <= SEGMENT_START. You should find those rows and decide how to dela with them.